# an inequality involving integral and differentiable function

Tags: calculus, integration

Could anyone help me to solve the following?

$f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $f'(x)\in(0,1)~\forall x\in (0,1), f(0)=0$, I need to show $\big(\!\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx\big)^2>\int_{0}^{1} f^3(x)\,dx$.

I started doing $F(x)=\big(\!\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,dt\big)^2-\int_{0}^{x} f^3(t)\,dt$ to show $F$ is increasing but I was stuck there.

Comment: You might have been on the right track, but your definition of $F$ has $x$ as a variable, but $x$ gets reused as the variable of integration on the RHS. I think you wanted $F(x)=\left(\int_{0}^{x}f(t)~dt\right)^2-\int_{0}^{x} f^3(t)~dt$.

Comment: What is $x$ in $F(x)$?  All the $x$'s on the RHS are local variables to the integrals.

Comment: Yessssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

Comment: OK. Now you've edited the question; it's time for you to do some more work. How are you going to differentiate $F$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f'>0$ and $f(0)=0$ we have that $f(x)$ is positive on $(0,1)$.
If we define
$$ G(x)=\left(\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,dt\right)^2-\int_{0}^{x}f(t)^3\,dt $$
we have $G(0)=0$ and by the fundamental theorem of Calculus
$$ G'(x) = 2\,f(x)\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,dt- f(x)^3 $$
hence it is enough to show that $f(x)^2 \leq 2\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,dt$. Pretty easy: by the constraint $f'\in(0,1)$,
$$ f(x)^2 = \int_{0}^{x} 2\, f'(t)\,f(t)\,dt \leq 2 \int_{0}^{x} f(t)\,dt. $$
Since $G(0)=0$ and $G'(x)\geq 0$ it follows that $G(x)\geq 0$ as wanted.